# How to redirect a file to another file (linux)

Tags: linux, bash

How can I like redirect a file to another file meaning say, I have two files `foo.txt` and `bar.sh`, now what I want is, how can I make it so that when I click on `foo.txt`, it executes `bar.sh`. You can actually give the answer in any language but I would prefer using shell script or python

Comment: `ln -s bar.sh foo.txt` ?

Comment: you would want to create a symbolic link done as @TedLyngmo points out via the ln command

Comment: it works, but not totally as excepted when i do that for an existing file it raises the exception saying "file already exists", so i tried running it after deleting the file, it ran perfectly but i want it to run with an existing file

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, [tag:bash] does not have the possibility to assosiate a file with a certain program like that. That's usually something you do in graphical file managers. Clicking a `.txt` file may cause it to open your favourite text file editor with the `.txt` file as an argument. Here's a [possible workaround](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/5067/391809) though.

Comment: Maybe this could actually work (i haven't tried it yet though), first i could store the file i need to create a symbolic link to and then delete the file and do the `ln` stuff

Comment: I don't think you should mix symbolic links into it. If you have some way of finding out which command it was that failed, just execute the assosiated command directly from `my_function`